# Convert PrintableString to UTF8STRING

Tags: openssl, asn.1, csr

Is there any easy way to convert PrintableString values to UTF8STRING in a CSR? I need the Organisation, State and Common Name in UTF8 but some users are generating the CSR with PrintableString and it takes time to get them to change their configuration file.

I already tried to look in the openssl documentation but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "conversion" needed when going from PrintableString to UTF-8 since PrintableString characters are a subset of US ASCII.  The first 127 characters of UTF8 are US ASCII.  Just copy the PrintableString value to the UTF8String field.

Comment: Is there any utility to do this or do I need to create a script to parse the CSR and do the change?

Comment: The exact way to do it depends on what tool you are using to decode (or parse) the CSR, and what target programming language you are using.  In C it would be a simple memcpy() or just a pointer assignment depending on the decoder you are using.